# Inserting value into target table dervived column from source table value with an IF ELSE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to import from a staging table(source) to a destination table(dest) in SQL Server. Some of the destination table values are derived from the source table values based on a conditional statement. The logic is somewhat like this

```
    IF source.col1=0 
    BEGIN
            IF source.col2=0
              BEGIN
                   dest.colA = 1
                   dest.colB = source.col3
              END
            ELSE
                 BEGIN
                        dest.colC= 1
                        dest.colD= source.col3
                 END
    ELSE IF source.col4>0 
            BEGIN
            dest.colD=1
            dest.colE=source.col3
           END
    ELSE
            BEGIN
            dest.colF=1
            dest.colG=source.col1
            END
   END
```

I am currently doing a merge from source table to destination table within a stored procedure and have other columns besides the above that map perfectly. How can i write this logic such that the destination table derived columns are set from source table columns based on the logic above? None of what I have tried so far works or makes sense to me. Thank you in advance for your help

Thank you M. Ali and phiosophicles. I am using this in a merge statement but now I am getting the error **Invalid object name 'Source'**.

I am not getting this error on any of my other merge statements. Source is below. I have anonymized to a certain extent so please let me know if it isn't clear

```
    MERGE dbo.Destination WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target
    USING
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, col3,   
CAST(LEFT(DATEADD(m,months,CONVERT(date,CONCAT(origination,'/01'))),7) as varchar(20))  as CalendarMonth,
col1, col2,col4 FROM dbo.Staging
) AS Source
    ON (Target.ID=Source.id
    AND Target.Month=Source.col3)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET
            Target.CalendarMonth=Source.CalendarMonth,
            Target.colF= (SELECT CASE WHEN col1>0 THEN 1 END AS colF FROM Source),
            Target.colD=(SELECT CASE WHEN col4>0 THEN 1 END AS colD
                                        FROM Source),
            Target.colC=(SELECT CASE WHEN col1=0 AND col2=0
                                        THEN 1 END AS colC FROM Source),
            Target.colB(SELECT CASE WHEN col1>0 AND col2
                                        THEN 1 END AS colB FROM Source),
            Target.colG=(SELECT CASE WHEN col1>0 THEN col1 END AS colG FROM Source),
            Target.colE=(SELECT CASE WHEN col4>0 THEN col3 END
                                        AS colE FROM Source),
            Target.PaidMonth=(SELECT CASE WHEN col1=0 AND col2=0
                                        THEN col3 END AS PaidMonth 
                                        FROM Source),
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT
            (Destination Table columns
            )
            VALUES
            (   Source values including derived values from above);

    END
```

GO

**UPDATE**:

I replaced the select statement in the derived columns with CASE WHEN col4>0 THEN col3 END and so on which got rid of the error. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Destination (ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColF, ColG)
Select CASE WHEN Col1 =  0 AND Col2 =  0 THEN 1    END AS ColA
      ,CASE WHEN Col1 =  0 AND Col2 =  0 THEN Col3 END AS ColB
      ,CASE WHEN Col1 =  0 AND Col2 <> 0 THEN 1    END AS ColC
      ,CASE WHEN Col1 =  0 AND Col2 <> 0 THEN Col3 
            WHEN Col1 <> 0 AND Col4  > 0 THEN 1    END AS ColD
      ,CASE WHEN Col1 <> 0 AND Col4 !> 0 THEN 1    END AS ColF
      ,CASE WHEN Col1 <> 0 AND Col4 !> 0 THEN Col1 END AS ColG
FROM SourceTable
```

Comment: Thanks @M.Ali. I added this to my merge, but I am getting an invalid object error on my source Alias now. I do not get this error in other merge statements I am using to populate other tables. I have added details in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL has two very different language constructs that both relate to "if one thing is true, do this, else that".

The IF/BEGIN/END construct demonstrated in the question is exclusively for *flow control* in T-SQL; that is, it should be used to wrap around whole blocks of code to control whether they are executed at all or not. You can put any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE query inside the BEGIN/END of an IF construct; you can also put data definition code (for example CREATE TABLE), variable assignment, and many other kinds of statement.

What you are trying to do, on the other hand, is control which *column expression* should be presented. This has to be done *within* a query (a SELECT, INSERT or UPDATE), and therefore uses a different T-SQL construct, CASE..END. M.Ali has provided a great example of how to use CASE..END in his answer, so I won't duplicate that. Just notice that each CASE..END block takes the place of a column in the SQL query.

Comment: Thanks @philosophicles. I added Ali's conditions to assign values to my target table in my merge statement, but I am getting an invalid object error on my source Alias now. I do not get this error in other merge statements I am using to populate other tables. I have added details in my original post.